# how to count elements after making a left join with doctrine

Tags: codeigniter, join, orm, doctrine, dql

i have 2 tables: "User" and "States". What i pretend to do, is to count how many users are from certain state, ie:

state       total users
santa fe       5
buenos aires   20

and so on.

I'm using codeigniter with doctrine, here's my code:

```
public function countByState(){
    $this->qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

    $this->qb->select('s.state_id', $this->qb->expr()->count('u.state'))
             ->from('models\States', 's')
             ->leftJoin('s.state_id' , 'u')
             ->leftJoin('models\User', 'u')
             ->groupBy('s.state_id');

    $query = $this->qb->getQuery();
    $obj = $query->getResult();

    return $obj;        
}
```

and this is the error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message '[Semantical Error] line 0, col 76 near 'u LEFT JOIN models\User': Error: Class models\States has no association named state_id' in C:\Desarrollo\new_frame_doctrine\site\application\libraries\data\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php on line 47

Comment: @AmitKumar thanx amit, i know how to do it in sql, but not in dql, so that was the question

Answer (score 0):

Please use this sql query

```
SELECT s.name,count(*) FROM `users` u left join `state` s on u.stateid=s.id 
 group by s.id;
```

In the code please change accordingly!!

I tried this by creating two tables named state (with fields `id and name`) 
and users(with fields `id, name and state_id`), It worked fine for me.

Cheers!!!